# Can transaction id be used to verify a transaction?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, raw-transaction, transaction-malleability

I have seen alot of questions here on "Transaction Malleability issue". Editing of transaction id can be done by miners or nodes which relay the transaction. 
What I want to know is

- whether the tx_id can be used to verify whether a transfer occurred successfully or not?
- Is the issue restricted to bitcoin only? What are other coins in which transaction malleability can occur ?
- Will it be solved in future upgrades of bitcoin core ?
- Can tx_id be used to retrieve raw transaction info (as it is public) ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed malleability means that the tx_id can change as long as the transaction is not in the blockchain yet. That means you can NOT rely on the tx_id. But:

- Once the transaction is in a block that is part of the blockchain, the tx_id does uniquely identify it and can be reliably used forever in the future to refer to it.
- Basically all other coins ever forked from Bitcoin have the same (and many more) problems.
- In Bitcoin it's already fixed by SegWit. The tx_id for SegWit transactions can not be malleated anymore (except by the person who has the private keys).

Comment: do popular exchanges use SegWit ?

Comment: More and more do. It was activated September last year (2017) but there was hardly any pressure to start using it until the fees became very high for a little while in December. Now SegWit adoption is up a lot and many more companies are working on adopting it.